# R - cambio parcial de una palabra en columnas

Tags: r

Tengo la siguiente table y quiero cambiar todas las apariciones de la palabra 'SchorschbrÃ¤u' por 'Schorschbräu'

```
57.70 |SchorschbrÃ¤u Schorschbock 57% |
43.00 |SchorschbrÃ¤u Schorschbock 43% |
41.00 |Sink The Bismarck!|
39.44 |SchorschbrÃ¤u Schorschbock 40% |
39.00 |Black Damnation VI - Messy |
32.00 |Tactical Nuclear Penguin |
30.86 | SchorschbrÃ¤u Schorschbock 31%|
29.00 |Dave |
28.00 |Ghost Deer|
27.00 |Samuel Adams Utopias|
```

He tratado de hacer `str_replace`, pero me lo convierte a vector y no quiero hacerlo:

```
df<- df%>% str_replace("SchorschbrÃ¤u", "Schorschbräu")
```

Cómo puedo mantener el df?

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocurre que `str_replace()` espera los siguientes parámetros posicionales:

```
str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)
```

Y `string` es:

> Input vector. Either a character vector, or something coercible to
> one.

Y en la forma en la que lo estás ejecutando estaría indicándole el `data.frame` completo (las funciones del universo `tidyverse` por defecto trasladan el objeto anterior al primer parámetro posicional). Lo que buscas es más bien algo así:

```
df <- df %>% 
         mutate(NombreColumna = str_replace(NombreColumna, "SchorschbrÃ¤u", "Schorschbräu"))
```

Con `mutate` hacemos una modificación de `NombreColumna` con el reemplazo deseado. Otra forma más general de aplicar el reemplazo es hacerlo en todas las columnas de tipo `character`:

```
df <- df %>% 
         mutate_if(is.character, str_replace, SchorschbrÃ¤u", "Schorschbräu") %>%
```